# Draw a bow tie using dots and ' * '

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and having an assignment which tell us to input an integer and make a 2*n+1 sized bow tie shape using '*' and '.', for example:

Input: 3

Output:

```
  *.....*
  **...**
  ***.***
  *******
  ***.***
  **...**
  *.....*
```

so i've come up with this:

```
  #include <iostream>

  using namespace std;
  int main()
  {
   int n;
   cin>>n;
   for(int i=1;i<=n+1;i++)
   {
      for (int p=i;p>=1;p--)
      cout<<"* ";
      for (int j=n;j>(i-1);j--)
      cout<<". ";
      for (int j=n;j>i;j--)
      cout<<". ";
      for (int j=i;j>=1;j--)
      cout<<"* ";
      cout<<endl;
   }

   for(int i=n;i>=1;i--)
   {
      for (int j=i;j>=1;j--)
      cout<<"* ";
      for (int j=n;j>(i-1);j--)
      cout<<". ";
      for (int j=n;j>i;j--)
      cout<<". ";
      for (int j=i;j>=1;j--)
      cout<<"* ";
      cout<<endl;
   }
  }
```

but my output looks like this:

Input: 3

Output:

```
  *.....*
  **...**
  ***.***
  ******** //<--1 redundant * at this row// 
  ***.***
  **...**
  *.....*
```

So i'm wondering is there any way to remove it, because if i try to tweak the loop it won't be the same shape anymore. Or is there a more efficent way to do this assignment?? I've been at it for hours! Thanks!

Comment: What is `star`?

Comment: Please attempt to indent your code. Indentation doesn't matter for the compiler, but it matters a lot for the humans reading the code.

Comment: Also, I suggest you take some time to read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert, and learn how to use a debugger to step through your code line by line.

Comment: Lastly, when you show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that is supposed to work (or at least *build*) the please make sure the code you show is is actually building without errors! Copy-paste the code you have, don't rewrite it into the question, as that may introduce unrelated errors (which you seem to have done).

Comment: Thank you for helping me edit my question @Someprogrammerdude, which i have done, if there is still something clarify, pls tell me. And i've editted the code, its the exact same in my compiler!

Comment: Your algorithm won't work as it is written. Your redundant star is caused because your outer loop `i` for `n=3` iterates from 1 to 4 but your star drawing algorithm counts _twice_ from 4 to 1, which gives you 8 stars. As @Someprogrammerdude pointed out, learn how to debug small programs and consider changing your algorithm so that it is easier to read.

Comment: an if statement could fix it. for example don't display the star one time when i is equal to 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe an if statement could fix the problem.
If statement in the 4th inner for loop of the first loop.

```
  for (int j=i;j>=1;j--){
       if(i != n+1 || j != 1){ 
           cout<<"* ";
       }
   }
  cout << endl;
```

when `i` is in the middle row meaning when `i == n+1` you have an extra star and when `j == 1` you have the last star in that middle row so this if statement won't display that last star. you can try this with any input it'll work.

Comment: Thank you so much! It did fix the problem, can't believe i didn't even think of using this instead! Tho I'm working on how to make this as minimal as possible, because that mess above is so ugly to look at. I'm hoping that I'll get better at c++ soon!

Comment: @PhạmSơn If you think I answered the question please [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Done! @Tyger :D